# Regex to test for a Latin letter in Go

Tags: regex, go, unicode

I'm trying to write a regex in Go to test for Latin letters only.

I know that `\p{Latin}` matches with any Latin script characters, but it also matches things such as Roman Numerals (e.g. "ⅻ"). 
That leads me to `\p{L}` which matches Unicode letters, but it matches any script, not just Latin.

Best I've been able to come with so far is two regexes with an `&&`:

```
latinRe := regexp.MustCompile(`\p{Latin}`)
letterRe := regexp.MustCompile(`\p{L}`)
if latinRe.Matches(testString) && letterRe.Matches(testString) {...}
```

I'm not happy that I can't test this as easily using something like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com). 
Is there a better way? More succinct? Performant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a range like the following to specify all the characters you *want* to match. Depending on the regex engine, one of the following should work:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zwSBfC/2): Adapted from [this link](https://www.regextester.com/94757)

```
[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff]
[A-Za-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xf6\xf8-\xff]
```

Another option is to negate specific characters from a Unicode character class:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zwSBfC/3)

```
[^\P{Latin}\p{N}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the second one, it's lazier. Note: I think `\P{L}` is the equivalent of my original regex instead of `\p{N}`. It's basically de morgan's applied to my `latinRe && letterRe == !( !latinRe || !letterRe)`

Comment: `\P{x}` is the opposite of `\p{x}` and `\P{L}` is any letter in any script whereas `\p{N}` is any number in any script. But yes, it's doing exactly that.